# Show that series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log(n))^{\log(\log(n))}}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Show that series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log(n))^{\log(\log(n))}}$$

is divergent . What inequality can we use here. i tried various method but none of these give any result. Any hint please .

Comment: Consider Cauchy's condensation test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence):
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log(n))^{\log(\log(n))}}\sim \int_2^\infty\frac{dx}{(\log x)^{\log(\log x)}}\stackrel{\log x\mapsto u}=
\int_{\log2}^\infty\frac{e^udu}{u^{\log(u)}}\stackrel{\log u\mapsto t}=
\int_{\log(\log2)}^\infty e^{e^t-t^2+1}d t.
$$
which clearly diverges.

Answer (score 3):

Take the exponential of the denominator. It can be seen that $\log\log(n) n$ is smaller than $e^n$ for large enough $n$. Since $x \mapsto e^x$ is monotonically increasing, this means the deonminator is smaller than $n$. The series can then be compared with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

By [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), the given series converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does, where $$a_n=\frac{2^n}{(n\log 2)^{\log(n\log 2)}}.$$ But $a_n\not\to 0$ (and in fact $a_n\to\infty$) as $n\to\infty$. Hence, the given series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for all $n\geq 2$,
$$
(\log n)^{\log \log n}  = e^{(\log \log n)^2 }  \le e^{4e^{ - 2} \log n}  < e^{\log n}  = n.
$$
Consequently
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(\log n)^{\log \log n} }}}  > \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}} ,
$$
and we are done since the harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: How do you prove $(\ln \ln n)^2 \leq 4e^{-2} \ln n$ ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon You consider $(\log\log x)^2/\log x$ for $x\geq 2$. By differentiation, it is not hard to show that it has a maximum at $x=e^{e^2}$. The value of this maximum is $4e^{-2}$.